# Angular 2 build generates links to root of server

Tags: javascript, angular, build

I`m trying to make my project runs in a test server, but when I run the ng build command and take the data from dist to there it always tries to load the js and css files from myserver.com/ and not from myserver.com/folder-of-project/

I thought it would be a problem on my code, but I created an empty project with angular-cli and did the build directly and also I got the same problem.

Am I missing something to do in the code before preparing the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `ng build --env=prod` this will build your project for production. `ng-build` it for local development. Also make sure inside your `index.html` the base href is as follows: `<base href="/">`

As mentioned in the comments, you'll need to append your project folder to your base href inside your `index.html` file

like so

```
<base href="/folder-of-project">
```

Comment: I tried also that, but it still tried to load the js files from the root folder of the server, instead of the folder where the page is included.

Comment: @DiegoPrestes ok, so how about inside your `index.html` modify the base href to be `<base href="/folder-of-project">`

Comment: Thanks, that worked for my test server environment.

Comment: @DiegoPrestes I've updated the answer to accomodate what we've discussed, can you please mark it as the answer. Thanks in advance.